# Invoking custom event from standard Aura Events

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning, aura

I am trying to find out the best way to invoke custom event when the Standard "Tab" becomes active.

Are we allowed to use Framework's events to listen and invoke our own events? Is there a better way to do this?

The reason why i am trying to leverage this Std. event is because my HTML elements within my component (On Relationship Tab Page) gets destroyed every time when i switch/move to another tab. So, my hope is to reconstruct or inject HTML to this component when "Relationship" tab becomes active.

**Example**
When i click "Relationship" tab, "aura:MethodCall" is invoked by AURA framework.
I wanted to listen to this event and invoke my own event.

[image]

Comment: My apologies for asking this question but how did you get the Relationships tab on the standard account page? I followed this link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/flexible_page_create_intro.htm but no success. Sorry Again!

Comment: I am using Lightning App Builder to create custom Tabs. There is a "Add Tab" button under Properties (Right Pane). It allows us to create Standard and Custom Tabs